# Python rjust() not working?

Tags: python

Hi I'm just toying with python and practicing printing stuff and formatting stuff.
And what I want to do is read in a number and print out asterisks corresponding to the number.
For example, if input is 5 the output would be,

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

(Note that it's right-aligned)

And below is my code, which merely prints out

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

when the input is 5.

```
a = input()
star = "*"
for num in reversed(range(1,a+1)):
    print (star*num).rjust(num)
```

And what I realized was if I change the num at the very last line to a constant integer, the code works fine, but I want the padding of each line to be same as the input number so it changes for every different numbers.
What is the current problem, and how do I fix it?

EDITIED------
OOPS! Figured it out!
It had to be
        print (star*num).rjust(a)
not num!!
It was just a dumb question :p

Comment: Sorry I edited the question once cuz it was all messed up! Sorry, new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: By editing the question at all, you're automatically more courteous than the 90% of new users that would just leave it all messed up ;-)

Comment: Nope, it was just my bad to pass current length as the parameter...:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `rjust` needs to be the length of the *longest* string, not the current string.

```
print (star*num).rjust(a)
```